# VisualVM : Comparing performance of two version of same application

Tags: java, performance, cpu-usage, heap-memory, visualvm

**I have refactored and tuned my java application.**

**I now want to compare the performance of newer and older version of the application , in terms of their individual CPU and heap memory usage.**

I am using `VisualVM` and `JDK 1.7`. I run them individually and monitor them using VisualVM. At the end all i have is two sets of graphs. This makes deciding which one is better difficult.

**Is there a metric that VisualVm provides , which can make deciding which version performs better easier. ?.**

Something like Average CPU used or Average Heap Used (if that is an accurate way of measuring performance) Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The Platform MBeans provide access to the CPU, memory and Garbage Collection data, so its possible to collect data from there and run statistical analysis against it:

CPU and Memory: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

Garbage Collection:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html